# Haskell print out 2d array

Tags: haskell, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print out my 2d array in game of life, but i'm not quite sure how to go on with it. So I need some help with my printArray function I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Her is the code below, everything is working.. Except printing it out in the right manner.

```
module GameOfLife where
import Data.List
import System.IO
import Text.Show
import Data.Array
import System.Random

width :: Int
width = 5

height :: Int
height = 5

data State = Alive | Dead deriving (Eq, Show)
type Pos = (Int,Int)
type Board = Array Pos State

startBoard :: Pos -> Board
startBoard (width,height) =
  let bounds = ((0,0),(width - 1,height - 1))
  in array bounds $ zip (range bounds) (repeat Dead)

set :: Board -> [(Pos,State)] -> Board
set = (//)

get :: Board -> [Pos] -> [State]
get board pos = map (board!) pos

neighbours :: Board -> Pos -> [Pos]
neighbours board c@(x,y) =
  filter (/= c) $ filter (inRange (bounds board)) [(x',y') | x' <- [x -             
 1..x + 1], y' <- [y - 1..y + 1]]

nextGen :: Board -> Board
nextGen board =(irrelevant code for the question..)


printArray :: Board -> String
printArray arr =
  unlines [unwords [show (arr ! (x, y)) | x <- [1..5]] | y <- [1..5]]
```

My output:

```
[((0,0),Dead),((0,1),Dead),((0,2),Dead),((0,3),Dead),((1,0),Dead),
((1,1),Dead),((1,2),Dead),((1,3),Dead),((2,0),Dead),((2,1),Dead),
((2,2),Dead)2,3),Dead)]
```

My preferable output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
 1 .  .  .  .  .
 2 n  n  n  .  .
 3 n  X  n  .  .
 4 n  n  n  .  .
 5 .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimal amount necessary to illustrate what you are asking about. For example, the `nextGen` functions seems irrelevant to your question. You can create a hard-coded `Board` to print. Also, show the output you actually get and explain how it differs from what you want. For more tips to improve your question to attract the answers you want, see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I think my nextGen is relevant to se how everything works. But now i've fixed my output suggestions

Comment: Your question is about **printing**. The only important data is the input to your print function. Where that data comes from is irrelevant. The **format** of the data is extremely important. You need to figure out how to transform the format of the input data into the format you wish to output.

Comment: Breaking problems into small parts is an extremely important skill as a programmer.  This means that you need to focus on the details which are important to the current problem **and ignore everything else**.

Comment: Your edit is much better. Can you find anything else to remove that is not important to your current question? Can you also add a `main` function with a contrived `Board` object that is used to call `printArray`?

Comment: Hmm, thank you, that's true.

Comment: Maybe the set and get functions? And no, I don't think i'm good enough in haskell to do that..

Comment: You can also think of it from another angle: what code do you need for `printArray` to compile? Get rid of anything that is not absolutely necessary for this.

Answer (score 1):

To start to answer your question, I suggest breaking the problem into several pieces:

1. Print out the numbers across the top.
2. Number each row as you print them.
3. Decide what symbol to print in each cell.

Tackle each of these pieces one at a time. If it helps, rather than think in terms of "printing" just build up a `String` object. Once you have a `String`, printing is pretty trivial.

Comment: I'm going to try this approach to begin with, thank you. I'll come back to you!